# Joining The Bandit Faction:

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> player.addtofaction 0001bcc0 #

What number should I replace the # with? And if I do this, will it wreck my questlines? Or cause any CTD's?

PS:

Can this be applied to Thalmor as well?

Answer (score 2):

From doing a quick google search, it appears that the command is built up from three parts:

```
player.addfaction <factionID> <True|False>
```

So for example, joining the Bandit faction would look like:

```
player.addfaction E0CD9 1
```

If you ever wanted to leave a faction, the `1` at the end would likely change to either a `0` or a `2`<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

You can see a full list of all the faction IDs [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)/Factions)

Comment: Ben, you're the best, the link is great too! I'm off to try the code and will post again my failure or success.

Comment: K, so the final and correct code line is: player.addtofaction E0CD9 1, I'm in the mines with a bandit right beside me and no red dots! JOY!!